# I need to pass the id in this function call in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I need to pass the value in the function call and use it to return according to that value passed.

The SlotDisabled function is the one in which I need to pass an Id.

```
SlotDisabled(id) {
    if(id === 'a1' || id === 'a2' || id === 'a3'){
        return (
            <Dimmer.Dimmable as={Table.Cell} style={{backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF', border: '0'}}>
                <Dimmer active={this.state.isMorningDisabled}/>
                <Icon size='large' style={{color: '#7ADBF0'}} name='s15' disabled={this.state.isMorningDisabled}/>
            </Dimmer.Dimmable>
        );
    }

    else if(id === 'a4' || id === 'a5' || id === 'a6'){
        return (
            <Dimmer.Dimmable as={Table.Cell} style={{backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF', border: '0'}}>
                <Dimmer active={this.state.isMorningDisabled}/>
                <Icon size='large' style={{color: 'yellow'}} name='sun' disabled={this.state.isMorningDisabled}/>
            </Dimmer.Dimmable>
        );
    }

    else if(id === 'a7' || id === 'a8' || id === 'a9'){
        return (
            <Dimmer.Dimmable as={Table.Cell} style={{backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF', border: '0'}}>
                <Dimmer active={this.state.isMorningDisabled}/>
                <Icon size='large' style={{color: 'grey'}} name='moon' disabled={this.state.isMorningDisabled}/>
            </Dimmer.Dimmable>
        );
    }
}

render(){
    {this.state.isNightDisabled ? (this.SlotDisabled()) : (this.state.isSelected ? (this.SlotSelected()) : (this.SlotUnselected()))}
}
```

Comment: I have tried passing as

(this.SlotDisabled('a1'))
and (this.SlotDisabled.bind('a1'))

Comment: What is the problem here? Are you getting any error or something?

Comment: just pass it ;) but Your render have to return something, now it won't work

Comment: this.SlotDisabled.bind('a1')  this is wrong. try this.SlotDisabled('a1').bind(this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning from your render function and that is the reason for your problem, as far as passing parameter is concerned, you would write `this.SlotDisabled('a1')`

```
render(){
    return <React.Fragment>{this.state.isNightDisabled ? (this.SlotDisabled('a1')) : (this.state.isSelected ? (this.SlotSelected()) : (this.SlotUnselected()))}</React.Fragment>
}
```